# cake(?) php specify form data pass to controller

Tags: database, forms, cakephp

I'm a complete cakepHp novice but understand some php.

I have a form that I'm using to get members to renew.  The only thing they need to specify is if they are changing how long a term they are renewing (1yr, 2...)

The rest of the data should be polled from their account in the phpMyAdmin database, USER table.  The fields of interest are: first_name, last_name, address1, address2, city, province, country, postal_code, email.  These should be passed to the form invisibly (i.e. user doesn't see them, but they go in to the invoice and the INVOICE table).

Additionally, there are 2 fields that will be written into the invoice table: notes (which will be ex. "user-renewal"), and is_renewal (which should = "1").

Thus far I have:

```
<form action="/member-renewals" id="UserDisplayForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>                         
    <ul class="formItemList"> 
    <li>
        <label>User Type</label>
        <select name="data[User][user_type_id]" id="UserUserTypeId">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="3">1-yr-Student ($40.00)</option>
            <option value="16">2-yr-Student ($72.00)</option>
        </select>
    </li>
```

But I have no clue how to query and set the other variables.  At this point the user is already logged in, but I tried:

```
<first_name="data[User][first_name]" id="UserFirstName">
```

to no avail...

Any thoughts?  Searches here are pointing me to ajax which is well beyond me.

---

edit: I'm not sure if this answers your questions.  I don't see anything relevant in the controller directory.  Logging in method (from login.ctp):

```
<?php
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'User Login');
    $this->viewVars['keywords'] = 'User Login';
    $this->viewVars['description'] = $this->Text->truncate(strip_tags('This is where users can login'), 150,array('ending'=>'...', 'html'=>false,'exact'=>false));  
    $this->layout = "default_full_no_h1";
?>
<script src="/js/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/flowplayer.embed-3.0.3.min.js"></script>

<?php echo $this->requestAction('/liveEditRegions/getRegion/37'); ?>   
<div class="greenForm">
<h2>Users Login</h2>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => '/' . $this->request->url));?>
    <ul class="formItemList" style="width:350px;padding-bottom:40px !important;"> 

        <li><?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('div'=>false, 'label'=>'Your Email Address'));?></li>
        <li class="clear"></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('div'=>false, 'label'=>'Password'));?></li>  
        <li class="clear"></li>        
        <li style="width:125px;"><button type="submit" class="submitBTN" style="float:left;">Login</button></li>          
        <li style="width:150px;text-align:center;margin-right:0px;margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $this->Html->link('Forgot Your Password','/users/forgotPassword',array('style'=>'line-height:60px;'));?>  </li>
        <li class="clear"></li>                
   </ul>         
            <div class='clear'></div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

edit: (controllers/UsersController.php):

```
function login() {
    $this->forceHTTPS();
    if ($this->userAuthenticate(false, true)) {
        $this->redirect('/users/index/');
    }
    $this->pageTitle = 'Login';
    if ($this->request->data) {
        if ($user_id = $this->User->validateLogin($this->request->data)) {

            $log = $this->addUserLog($user_id, 'Login');

            $params = array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.id' => $user_id
                ),
                'contain' => array(
                    'UserType'
                )
            );

            $this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
            $user = $this->User->find('first', $params);

            $this->Session->write('User', $user['User']);
            $this->Session->write('UserType', $user['UserType']);

            $this->Session->setFlash('Logged in successfully', 'flash_success');
            /*
              if(!$redirect = $this->Session->read('userRedirected')){
              $this->Session->delete('userRedirected');
              $redirect = '/users/index';
              $this->Session->delete('livetoolsRedirected');
              }
             */
            //$this->redirect($redirect); 
            $this->redirect('/users/index/');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to authenticate - please contact the CSPT administrator', 'flash_error');
            $this->request->data['User']['password'] = '';
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I think this is what you're looking for (from: userscontroller.php).  This was the OLD renewal procedure.  The new procedure the users will select the type of renewal.  I will post this right after.:

```
function cronRenew() {
    /*
      December - �Dues are due�:
      email is sent to all active members, who have not yet paid, indicating dues are due
      invoice is automatically generated for the members� dues
     */

    //Initiate the email component
   /* $email = new CakeEmail();

    $params = array(
        //'fields' => array('User.id', 'User.first_name', 'User.last_name', 'User.address1', 'User.created', 'User.city', 'User.province', 'User.country', 'User.postal_code', 'User.email'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.status' => 'active',
            'User.enabled' => '1',
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'User.id'
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'UserType'
        ),
        'recursive' => 1
    );

    $this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    $users = $this->User->find('all', $params);

    //now that we have all active users, lets generate them invoices for renewal of memberships
    $errorEmailList = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {

        if (isset($user['UserType']) && $user['UserType']['annual_dues_amount'] > 0 && !$this->User->hasUserPaidForTheComingYear($user['User']['id'])) {

            //Create the Invoice
            $invoice = array(
                'Invoice' => array(
                    'user_id' => $user['User']['id'],
                    'first_name' => $user['User']['first_name'],
                    'last_name' => $user['User']['last_name'],
                    'address1' => $user['User']['address1'],
                    'city' => $user['User']['city'],
                    'province' => $user['User']['province'],
                    'country' => $user['User']['country'],
                    'postal_code' => $user['User']['postal_code'],
                    'email' => $user['User']['email'],
                    'notes' => "User Membership Renewal",
                    'is_renewal' => '1',
                    'InvoiceItem' => array(
                        '0' => array(
                            'name' => 'User Membership Renewal',
                            'description' => 'Renewal for ' . $user['User']['first_name'] . ' ' . $user['User']['last_name'],
                            'price' => $user['UserType']['annual_dues_amount'],
                            'quantity' => '1',
                            //'hst_rate'=>$this->User->taxRate
                            'hst_rate' => 0
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

---

Edit:  New renewal method (from: usercontroller.php):

```
# Send email of the Overdue @02/March/2015  
function cronInvoiceOverdueNew() {

    //Initiate the email component
    $email = new CakeEmail();

    $month = date('m');
    if($month < 3 && $month > 5){
        exit;
    }

    $params = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.status' => 'active',
            'User.enabled' => '1',
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'User.id'
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'UserType'
        ),
        'recursive' => 1
    );

    $this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    $users = $this->User->find('all', $params);

    $errorEmailList = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $inGoodStanding = $this->User->isUserInGoodStanding($user['User']['id']);
        $userPaidLastYear = $this->User->hasUserPaidForThisYearInTheLastYear($user['User']['id']);
        if ($inGoodStanding == false && !$userPaidLastYear) {
            try {
                //$month = '5';
                if ($month == '3') {
                    /* $message = "Attention " . $user['User']['first_name'] . " " . $user['User']['last_name'] . "\n\n" . "This is a notification to let you know you have outstanding invoice(s) that must be paid within a month or they will be charged a $10 late fee.\n\n" . 
                      "Thanks\n" .
                      */
                    /*$message = "You have an outstanding membership renewal invoice. Please follow the following link to pay your annual membership dues. A $10.00 late fee will be charged to invoices not paid by the end of February.\n\n" .
                            "Username: " . $user['User']['email'] . "\n" .
                            "Thank you for your continuing support \n" .
                      $message = "Thank you for your patience while undergoing site wide upgrades. Please note there will be no penalty for late renewals thus far. Please login and renew your account by visiting the 'Renewals' link at the bottom of the 'Memberships' dropdown. Please select your correct membership type and submit. An invoice will be created which you can select by clicking 'view' and pay by following through. A late fee of $10 will apply commencing May 2nd, 2015.";       

                    $email->subject('Avoid late fee for annual dues @ ' . Configure::read('Site.name'));
                } elseif ($month == '4') {
                    /* $message =  "Attention " . $user['User']['first_name'] . " " . $user['User']['last_name'] . "\n\n" . 
                      "This is a notification to let you know you have outstanding invoice(s) that if not payed by months end will have a $10 late fee added.\n\n" .
                      "Thanks\n" .
                     */
                    /*$message = "You have an outstanding membership renewal invoice. Please follow the following link to pay your annual membership dues. A $10.00 late fee will be charged to invoices not paid by the end of February.\n\n" .
                            "Username: " . $user['User']['email'] . "\n" .
                            "Thank you for your continuing support \n" .                               
                      $message = "Please log in and renew your account by visiting the \"Renewals\" link at the bottom of the \"Memberships\" dropdown. Please select your correct membership type and submit. An invoice will be created which you can select by clicking 'view' and pay by following through. A late fee of $10 will apply after 30 days, commencing May 2nd, 2015.";      

                    $email->subject('Last reminder for dues renewal @ ' . Configure::read('Site.name'));
                } elseif ($month == '5') {
                    /*$message = "Attention " . $user['User']['first_name'] . " " . $user['User']['last_name'] . "\n\n" . "This is a notification to let you know you have outstanding invoice(s).\n\n" .
                            "Thanks\n" .
                    $message = "Urgent: your account must be renewed by today to avoid late fees. Please log in and renew your account by visiting the \"Renewals\" link at the bottom of the \"Memberships\" dropdown. Please select your correct membership type and submit. An invoice will be created which you can select by clicking 'view' and pay by following through. A late fee of $10 will apply commencing tomorrow, May 2nd, 2015.";        

                    $email->subject('Outstanding Invoices @ ' . Configure::read('Site.name'));
                }


                $message .= "\n\n Renewing your membership allows you to be nominated for the Society awards, stand for election to various committees and, when appropriate, ensures your student's access to presentation and travel awards. The funds collected from membership dues and donations support the educational activities of the Society including the Trainee Travel Bursaries.";

                $email->lineLength = 200;
                $email->from(Configure::read('Site.contact.email'));
                $email->sender(Configure::read('Site.contact.noreply'));
                $email->to($user['User']['email']);
                $email->bcc('admin@xxxxxx.org');
                $email->send($message);
                //echo "<br/>".$user['User']['email']."<br/><br/>";
                echo nl2br($message);
                //echo "<hr/><br/><br/>";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $errorEmailList[] = $user['User']['first_name'] . ' ' . $user['User']['last_name'] . ' - ' . $user['User']['email'];
            }
            //die();                
        }
    }
    die('Reminder Email Cron Completed');
}
```

Comment: You need to pass Data from Controller to view by setting variables which can be accessible by view. What coding you did in Controller?

Comment: Why you posted the code generated by the `from` helper instead of the view that generated it? Also how are you loggin in your users? depending on that is how you can get your logged in user data. CakePHP is an MVC framework, and you are asking about to pass data from controller, so you defnitly should post your controller code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasn't aware.  I am going to look at the controller now and will post as soon as I can figure out where it is...

Comment: Hi friends, any thoughts?  I posted the requested info...any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your login code, it seems you store the user in your session. So you can access it in your controller, and send it to your view, like this:

```
$user = $this->Session->read('User');
$this->set('user', $user);
```

This creates the variable $user which you can now use in your view to access the user object's properties, eg:

```
<?php echo $user['first_name']; ?>
```

I do have the impression you're not very familiar with CakePHP, perhaps you should try reading up on the basics: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was about to give up!  You're right, I am not familiar -though I did read the documentation (steep learning curve).  I have found a bunch of methods but was missing the piece you said about pre-defining the variable.  I know this must be done already because on login it says, "Welcome, " first_name...  Thank you again, I will report back.

Comment: Success!  Well mostly.  I used:  if (($this->Session->read('User', $user['User'])) != '')...     For some reason the variable returned 'Array' on login, but only when logged in, so that works.  Thank you for the help, very appreciated.